# Windows GetPixel typedef C++

Tags: winapi

How do I define the type for GetPixel and / or what else am I missing to use GetPixel?

```
#include <windows.h>
class PollPixelArray
{
public:
    PollPixelArray(HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor);
    unsigned long createHex(int r, int g, int b);
private:
    PollPixelArray();
};

PollPixelArray::PollPixelArray(HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor)
{
    GetPixel(hdcMonitor, 50, 100);
}

unsigned long createHex(int r, int g, int b){
    return (((r & 0xff) << 16) + ((g & 0xff) << 8) + (b & 0xff));
}
```

Always returns the same unsigned long / DWORD / COLORREF no matter the X or Y co-ordinates.

```
while (tempX<40){
    COLORREF tempREF = GetPixel(hdcMonitor, tempX, tempY); //COLORREF | unsigned long | 
    unsigned int dummy = GetRValue(tempREF);
    std::cout << "RGB: " << ("%d", dummy);
    dummy = GetGValue(tempREF);
    std::cout << "," << ("%d", dummy);
    dummy = GetBValue(tempREF);
    std::cout << "," << ("%d", dummy);
    std::cout << " at " << ("%d", tempX) << ", " << ("%d", tempY) << std::endl;
    tempX++;
    tempY++;
}
```

The loop always returns 255,255,255 for the RGB values.

The HDC Callback function:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "pollpixelarray.h"
BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{

    PollPixelArray::PollPixelArray(hdcMonitor, lprcMonitor);

    return true;
}

void main()
{
    EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, MonitorEnumProc, 0);

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand.. the return type is a COLORREF

Comment: When I print it, it always has the same value no matter what location pixel, there must be something missing. I did a little research and it was suggested that "typedef WINAPI GetPixel(hdc hdc, int posX, int posY)" would fix. eitherway the GetPixel does not seem to work ATM.

Comment: You're not storing [the result anywhere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144909(v=vs.85).aspx), what is that code supposed to do?

Comment: `GetPixel` works correctly. Whatever is wrong is in the code that you wrote.

Comment: Have edited to show my while loop outputting the RGB at relative X and Y's

Comment: Post GetRValue and the others

Comment: Either the coords are outside the clipping rectangle, or the DC is not valid. But please do know that `GetPixel` works. So you need to look at your own code that calls it.

Comment: GetRValue, GetGValue and GetBValue all post
255,255,255 at X, Y. Which means the whole screen should be white on both my monitors if this were the case.

Comment: The HDC is passed through a CALLBACK function:

Comment: Why are you so secretive about where you got your DC from?

Comment: lol, sorry, have updated post.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing at all to do with typedefs and `GetPixel` works correctly. There are a couple of plausible explanations for the behaviour you observe:

1. The device context is not valid, or
2. The coordinates that you pass are outside the bounds of the device.

Looking at your code, both are likely to be the case,

The documentation for the `hdc` parameter of `EnumDisplayMonitors` says:

> If this parameter is NULL, the hdcMonitor parameter passed to the callback function will be NULL, and the visible region of interest is the virtual screen that encompasses all the displays on the desktop.

The documentation for `GetPixel` says:

> If the pixel is outside of the current clipping region, the return value is CLR_INVALID (0xFFFFFFFF defined in Wingdi.h).

Comment: It does return the correct values for the resolution of the screen so it appears the device context is legitimate: Though I don't see how the co-ordinates of 0-40, 0-40 etc. could be off screen?

Comment: When you debug this you will see that what I say above is correct. And indeed both problems can occur. Option 1 is the first hurdle to overcome. Once you've got past that, recognise that the device context may not have `0,0` as its origin.

Comment: If I set the co-ordinates dynamically via the results of the lprcRECT like this:
x = (lprcMonitor->right - lprcMonitor->left);
y = (lprcMonitor->bottom - lprcMonitor->top);
tempX = x/2;
tempY = y/2;
The results are the same and should always be on-screen should it not?

Comment: Yes, the hdcMonitor is null. How can I select which monitor to connect to?

Comment: It's explained in the documentation. I think that I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: Do you still need help here, or have we got to the bottom of this question?